# Python multiple dimension array with range function has negative indexes

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I am trying to define a two dimension array with for loops using range function:

```
>>> takobaba =  [['A' for i in range(0, 6, 1)] for j in range(0, 6, 1)]
>>> takobaba [-1][-1]
'A'
```

As you can see i get an output for index -1, -1 even i called range function from 0 to 6 with step 1 for both dimensions. Could you please help me to understand the reason and fix this error?

Comment: indexing with negative value means reverse indexing, from last element up to first element...so `[-1][-1]` means returning last element of last row

Comment: is there a way to stop this reverse indexing for my work

Comment: @takobaba you could write your own list class. But... why?

Comment: You mean, you don't want to get elements with negative values?

Comment: I am doing some addition and removal on indexes so this kind of bothers me but i figured out a way if thats how python works. I am going to prevent negative indexes. Thank you all.